# Debug Lightroom with ZeroBrane --> Error

Tags: lua, zerobrane, lightroom

I'm trying to start developing a Lightroom plugin and I'm using the ZeroBrane IDE for it because debugging should be possible with it. I followed the instruction from [here](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/debugging-lightroom-plugins-zerobrane-studio-ide).

But I allways get an error when I run the plugin within Lightroom. The message says:

```
module 'mobdebug' not found:
no field package.preload['mobdebug']
no file './mobdebug.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/mobdebug.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

In the folder `/usr/local/lib/` there is no folder called `/lua/5.1/`

I guess it has to do with my LUA installation but I could not figure it out yet. I hope you can help me somehow.

I use macOS High Sierra (10.13.4) and Lightroom Classic CC (7.3.1).

thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the mismatch between the Lightroom version and what's specified in `Info.lua` file (in the VERSION element). You'll need to update it to match your 7.3.1 version. You may also want to check the discussion on the page you referenced, as similar issues have been discussed and resolved there.

Comment: thanks Paul but I already did that:
- I changed the Version in Info.lua file to VERSION = { major=7, minor=3, revision=1, build=1167660 }
- I also checked the discussion on your homepage but there was no solution for that problem.